# Multiply raster with a variable ArcMap 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator

I want to multiply my raster with a value that would be a parameter in ModelBuilder.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are simply multiplying each cell in your raster with a value then all you need to run is the [Times](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/times.htm) tool. You do not need to run that in a model but if you do you can expose the parameters.